# Why is running a script manually which is scheduled in CRONTAB triggering email alert?

Tags: linux, unix, cron, rhel, postfix-mta

I have crontab scheduled as something as

MAILTO=myemail@domain.com,anotheremail@domain.com
00 09 * * sun /opt/add.sh

Every sunday the job runs and triggers an email.
When I run the add.sh script manually anytime, even then email is triggered why?

Expectation is manually running the script, it should not trigger email

Comment: I guess the answer to your question is somewhere buried in the text of /opt/add.sh. If you need help from the community to find the issue, you'll have to share it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.